# How should I filter the data that I got from overpass-api-interpretor to look like data from overpass turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I just started using Overpass Api yesterday. I am querying data from overpass-api with this method.

```
  var OVERPASS_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter',
      OVERPASS_API_REQUEST =
      '[out:json];(' + 'node["highway"](BOUNDS););' + 'out center;>;',
    OVERPASS_BOUNDS_REGEX = /BOUNDS/g;

 let res = await axios({
    url: OVERPASS_API_ENDPOINT,
    data: OVERPASS_API_REQUEST.replace(OVERPASS_BOUNDS_REGEX, bboxstr),
    method: 'get',
    timeout: 25000,
  })
```

currently, this returns

```
  {
    type: 'node',
    id: 66250246,
    lat: 34.2146702,
    lon: -84.8261852,
    tags: { highway: 'turning_circle' }
  },
  ... 4379 more items
```

On Overpass Turbo, with about the same bbox it shows fewer data points. So I am wondering what is the best way to filter the data I received to be similar to the one I found on Overpass Turbo? Also, why is there so many nodes with the same tags, I know I filtered it by the highway tag, but can the same node belong to more than one specific lat and long?

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible as it stands. Can you post the full string that gets passed as "data" to await_axios, and the corresponding overpass turbo query as shortlink? 
Also, are you sure you want to filter for highway nodes? This seems a rather unusual thing to do.

Comment: hmm it turns out its returning data outside my bbox??  the full query is `[out:json];(' + 'node["highway"]({{34.21092368471588,-118.6453487197585,34.212720315284116,-118.64752128024149}}););' + 'out center;>;`

Comment: That's incorrect Overpass QL syntax: you need to remove those curly braces {{ }} for your bbox. In addition, for nodes, you can leave out the  >; towards the end, as it has no impact on the result.

Comment: `http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=(node["highway"](34.21092368471588,-118.6453487197585,34.212720315284116,-118.64752128024149););out center;` this is the string, but it returns data outside the bbox?

Comment: you may need to change the % signs after you send a request on your browser

Comment: I just made a new question here: `https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368074/does-overpass-return-data-inside-the-bbox` thought it would be more professional to not ask questions in answers.