# Overpass not returning data within my given bounding box

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have been using this endpoint to query data from the highway tags. But I am receiving data way outside the bbox? Is there something wrong with my query?

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=(node["highway"](34.21092368471588,-118.6453487197585,34.212720315284116,-118.64752128024149););out center;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bbox is at odds with the overpass syntax, and should read:  (south,west,north,east). As you have swapped east and west, your bbox spans the whole globe.

Correct query would be:

(node["highway"](34.21092368471588, -118.64752128024149,34.21272031528411, -118.6453487197585););out center;

More details are available here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Bounding_box

Comment: hey how would i conver this to a geojson?